# getContent() throws ApexPagesGenericException 404

Tags: json, exception, static-resources

When trying to retrieve a json file from a zip file, I get the following error:

> Error: System.VisualforceException:
> core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesGenericException: 404 status code
> return from request to
> https://cs161.salesforce.com/resource/1617882278000/testData/questionnaires.json?inline=1

Source Code:

```
StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id,NamespacePrefix,SystemModstamp FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'testData' LIMIT 1];
String prefix = sr.NamespacePrefix;
if( String.isEmpty(prefix) ) {
    prefix = '';
} else {
    //If has NamespacePrefix
    prefix += '__';
}
//Get the path of MyJsonFile.json file in Zip static resource
String srPath = '/resource/' + sr.SystemModstamp.getTime() + '/' + prefix + 'testData/questionnaires.json'; 
PageReference pg = new PageReference( srPath );
String body = pg.getContent().toString(); <--------------- Error occurs here
System.debug(body);
```

Any pointers how to debug this error?

The file is there, I validated the path, downloaded it and extracted it.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Figured it was happening because of namespace prefix. So I appended a static namespace prefix in the resource path string with '__' appended.
Hope this helps.